# What is the non-emergency 24 medical assistance number in iceland?

Tags: health, iceland

I'm looking for the equivalent of the UK's NHS 111 number, for 24-hour medical assistance, in Iceland.

The [NHS webpage](http://www.nhs.uk/NHSEngland/Healthcareabroad/countryguide/Pages/healthcareinIceland.aspx) says:

> **1770** – medical assistance

[The US embassy disagrees with this](https://is.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/local-resources-of-u-s-citizens/doctors/), but then goes on to contradict themselves:

> For urgent after-hours primary care, call **1700**.
>
> [...]
>
> From 23:30 to 8:00 you should call **1770** as described above.

I don't know icelandic, but this first number seems to be backed up by [a clinic website](https://www.hsu.is/heilsugaeslan-selfossi/vik-i-myrdal/):

> SÍMI VAKTÞJÓNUSTU LÆKNA OG HJÚKRUNARFRÆÐINGA Á HSU ER **1700**

Meanwhile, the [visit reykjavik website](http://www.visitreykjavik.is/important-phone-numbers) lists a different number again:

> Health Care Services (out of hours) Tel: **1170**

It's shocking how inconsistent this all is. Which one is correct?

None of these numbers are working for me.

---

Update: After contacting those websites, all have confirmed that they meant to type **1770**

Comment: Apparently the rule is, "170, but choose _exactly one_ of the digits to press twice".

Comment: 1770 is supported by http://icelandreview.com/important-phone-numbers and https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/iceland.html with the latter suggesting that the service is only available in Reykjavik.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no single number in Iceland like the NHS 111.

Both the numbers 1770 and 1700 are in use but I think the 1170 number is incorrect.

The number 1700 is supposed to be a country wide telephone service for health related questions. I'm unable to find any specific website for it but many health centers outside the greater Reykjavik area refer to it as an off-hour contact number for non-emergencies.

1770 is the number of an off-hour medical clinic - Læknavaktin, located in the Reykjavik area. Their telephone service is open 17-8 weekdays and all day weekends and holidays. Website: http://laeknavaktin.is/ (only in Icelandic). If you are in the Reykjavik area and you need medical advice outside of normal hours you should probably use that number.